# Why I can't install python virtual environment?

Tags: python, macos, python-venv

I try to install virtual environment using : `python -m venv .venv`

But it says it can't find a module called `venv`.

[image]

Comment: Please show output of `python -V` or try `python3 -m venv` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are using the default Python version 2.X. Try this to see if that is the case:

```
python --version
```

If the default is 2.X, then it does not come with the `venv` library. You need to explicitly call python3:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

Comment: FYI, MacOS 12.3 removed Python2

Comment: I did not know that. BTW, I'm still running 12.2.1

Answer (score -2):

Execute first this line to install virtual-enviornment and than execute your line.

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `python -m venv` (assuming Python 3) and doesn't address the error of actually using `venv` module.